# Wiped out and sold my Mac without logging out of iCloud. Can I remove the lock remotely?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud

I wiped out and sold my Macbook Pro (Intel with T2 chip) with Catalina and I didn't log out of iCloud before doing so.

My buyer was locked out when he tried to log onto Apple Music. Now he is stuck in Recovery mode.

In my Apple ID account, my sold Macbook Pro appear in my list of devices, and I have the option to "Remove from account"

Also, "Find My Mac" is NOT enabled on it.

What happens if I press "Remove from account"?
Will it brick the laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought an iMac and it was wiped but not logged out of iCloud like you describe.

I could not continue install, contacted the old owner and they clicked « remove from account » and I could then continue and it still works fine.